# plugin inside a wordpress theme

Tags: plugins, themes

Ok so I have this theme and inside it is a plugin. When i installed and activate the theme the I can use the plugin as it appears on the left side bar on my dashboard screen but when i change theme i am unable to use the plugin. Is there a way for me to activate that plugin so that I can use it whenever? I have tried to install the plugin by it self without the theme by removing it from the theme folder , zipping it and then trying to install it but that did not work.

Comment: What's the name of the theme? And can you describe what this "plugin" does a little more?

Comment: the plugin is a slider but i can only use the slider when i active the theme that it was included it with.

Comment: This is the theme http://themeforest.net/item/rhapsody-wordpress-multi-purpose-theme/full_screen_preview/3675980 and this was the plugin that was included with it when i intalled it on wordpress http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246 -- but i can only use the slider when the theme is activated. I found another theme that i like but want to use this slider on it.

Comment: Well that's quite a generic question, "how to use plugin X with theme X". Have you tried one of the [many other slider plugins](http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=slider) out there? They tend to offer better support for use in *any* theme.

Comment: well the slider can be used with any theme. I dont have the installation for the slider. I was included in the zip file for the theme that it came with

Comment: Well without seeing the contents of the ZIP, we can't help. And since it's a paid-for theme, you'll be in breach of terms if you upload it for us. Stalemate!

Answer (score 1):

This question is misleading, I'm not sure you understand how Themes/Plugins work. It's not that you have a plugin *inside* the theme. Rather the theme has *plugin like* features (or custom functionality).

I personally find this to be bad practice and prefer when themes come with plugins instead of trying to bundle it all together.

For what it's worth from looking at the source I can see the the slider plugin appears to be layer slider [available here.](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246) You may also be able to extract it from the theme but often this turns out to be a giant pain.